# Cannot run Eclipse / Android SDK Project - Errors of Unknown Origin

Tags: java, android, xml

All the files look fine to me - anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Amani Swann

ERRORS:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Content is not allowed in trailing section. strings.xml /Linking Manager/res/values line 7  Android XML Format Problem
invalid resource directory name AndroidManifest.xml /Linking Manager/bin/res    line 1  Android AAPT Problem
error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)   strings.xml /Linking Manager/res/values line 7  Android AAPT Problem
Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Android Backups\3.1.2013 @1111pm\MyAndroidApp\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist Linking Manager     Unknown Android Packaging Problem

main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

main2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="User Settings:" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Data Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10MB" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Data" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Bandwidth Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/textView4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:gravity="left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="10kbs" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
    <TextView android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Unlimited Bandwidth" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="WiFi Time Limit" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<TimePicker android:id="@+id/timePicker1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="50.0dip" android:layout_weight="1.0" />
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Blocked Sites - [ex: www.xxx.com]" android:ems="10" />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mkyong.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".main2" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".home" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".App2Activity" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

AppActivity.java (primary java file)

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button button;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

// add button listener
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings Menu");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
        .setMessage("Link or Delete?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Link",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
        //start new activity

        Intent intentApp2Activity = new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intentApp2Activity);

        // if this button is clicked, close
        // current activity
        AppActivity.this.finish();
    }
  })
        .setNegativeButton("Delete",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // if this button is clicked, just close
                // the dialog box and do nothing
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
}}
```

App2Activity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}

}
```

Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Linking Manager</string>
<string name="button1">Button1</string>
<string name="button2">Button2</string>
<string name="button3">Button3</string>    
</resources>
```

ERRORS: (shown above at the top of this thread)

All the files look fine to me - anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

- Amani Swann

Comment: There must be more to your AndroidManifest.xml. If there's not, that's the problem.

Comment: **Read** your errors: `AndroidManifest.xml:  XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`

Comment: post the complete AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Posted! (in the same place - it's just complete now [apologies])

Comment: Any suggestions anyone?

Comment: @Amani Swann  try below solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="NFC Linking Manager" />
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Linksys Router (Home)" android:onClick="onPopupBtClick" />
<Button android:id="@+id/Button2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Netgear Router (Office)" />
<Button android:id="@+id/Button3" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cisco Router (Office)" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I edited your layout like **android:id="@+id/Button3"** in every components

Do same for main2.xml